# Компоновка в файле для приложения андроид

Tags: android, java

Суть такая, что моя программа состоит из одного `public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`. Необходимо по собиытию в методе onCreate реализовать запись в файл следующим путем:

```
    String filename = "myfile";
    String string = "Hello world!";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try
    {  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
       outputStream.close();}
    catch (Exception e)
    {  e.printStackTrace(); }
```

openFileOutput - подчёркивается красным, ругается на то, что это не известные метод. Когда вставляю этот же код в класс Class наследуемый от Activity все норм. Я не знаю как вызвать запись в файл с моего ресивера обратившись к классу Class. Получается что для записи нужно наследование от  Activity, а у меня ресивер как я его наследую от Activity? Подскажите, что надо дописать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В методе `onReceive()` `BroadcastReceiver`'а первым аргументом вам приходит `Context`, так и используйте его:

```
context.openFileInput(…);
```

Comment: Нет, но вы можете задавать свои вопросы на этом ресурсе, и вам обязательно кто-нибудь поможет.